# What is the effect of the surface area of an electrode on the emf of a cell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

I've read that a platinum electrode has no effect in a hydrogen fuel cell - why is this?
Also, what is the effect of the surface area of an electrode such as zinc in a zinc copper cell?

Comment: Area? No - it only increases the maximum Current, However surface curvature, crystallographic texturing, and crystallographic strain can, which often confounds results and leads people to believe that area does.

Comment: To amend my comment, Imagine you have a second identical electrochemical cell. Does the emf increase? No, the EMF is the same even though you have doubled the surface area in this case.

Comment: I think you Should split the is question into two independent questions, as they are independent of each other. This would make it easier to provide an appropriate answer.